# Must You Have a Correct EC2 AMI ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami

I tried launching a Linux Instance with cloud formation Using just a random generated AMI id in my head and it did not work. Must I have the exact id provided by AWS like `ami-0b69ea66ff7391e80`?

```
Resources:
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami- <******> # Amazon Linux AMI in N.Virginia
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: EC2 Linux
```

```
ami-0b69ea66ff7391e80
```

Comment: Of course, if you just type some random numbers for an AMI ID, it isn't going to work because the AMI won't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is a operating system (OS) image to boot the server (EC2 Instance).

The AMI contains the OS (eg Linux or Windows), plus software, applications and any desired data. You can use a pre-provided AMI from AWS (base OS with default software) or the AWS Marketplace with custom software bundled. Even you can create one of your own with software and data pre-installed.

When starting an Amazon EC2 instance, an AMI must be specified. This AMI will then be copied to the boot disk for the instance to start. Thus, if you do not specify an AMI, the instance cannot boot so it will be disallowed.

Answer (score -1):

```
Resources:
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      ImageId: ami-0b69ea66ff7391e80 # Amazon Linux AMI in N.Virginia
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: EC2 Linux
```

*Go to your console
Attempt to launch an Instance
Copy the AMI id e.g ami-0b69ea66ff7391e80
and then launch using cloud formation template generated*